# I have a video background bootstrap page. How can I make a transparent overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I prepared the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/30/ and as you can see I already successfully included the video as a background on the main section. Later on there's a green section with some text and a black square. And now - is it possible to cut off the green background inside of this png file and leave there the video from the background? Ideally it would have alignment absolute, so it would show exactly the same area that is on that place in the original video. I thought about surrounding it with class:

```
.transparent{

}
```

but I don't know if it is possible to cut off the center of this square. Basically I would like to have an effect like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pq4C.jpg

Comment: I think the only way to achieve it is using a solid color PNG with a empty square - like a mask - as background of this div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your fiddler and with did it with shadow-box filling the outside with green. Tell me if it suits your needs.

I added two new CSS properties with:

```
.transparent{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 999, 0, 1);
    overflow:hidden;

}

#imgBox{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 999, 0, 1);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/31/

Regards

Comment: thanks, one question - with that solution, how do you take care about expanding the whole green area horizontally when user resize his browser? Should I just put more pixels (bigger dimension) in the box-shadow property?

Comment: Yes, just replace the 1000px to 99999 or other ludicrous value. Also I didn't replicate your green box color perfectly, you need to change it to your specific needs :)

Comment: @randomuser1 if your problem is solved don't forget to close the question

Answer (score 0):

When ever I do this, I like to use the `pseudo-selector` `::before`.

Basically, say your banner's name was `.main-banner`. Without touching your html, you can add a div before it with just css.

Your css would be something like this:

```
.main-banner:before{
  content: "";
  position: relative; /* position on top */
  width: 100%; /*full width*/
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(25,29,34,0.35); /*your background color */
}
```

I haven't worked in bootstrap for a while so I forget the class name for a hero-image, but you get the idea.

Edit: updated your fiddle, you would need to use `video-container2`.
[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/32/).

Comment: thanks, are you sure about this solution? In the fiddle you attached it doesn't work, at least in chrome :(

Comment: It works, just had a really light background, look at this one, I made it darker.
http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/35/

Comment: I don't see it working either. I think you might have missed the point. Your solution isn't for he's problem

Comment: Yup, my mistake, misunderstood it completely. I figured he wanted it as a transparent overlay over the video.